# Wrong path from intent when receiving a file using Android Beam, only on certain phones

Tags: android, file, kotlin, nfc, android-beam

I'm implementing file transfer through Android Beam in my app.

I have 2 phone I can use for testing: a Samsung Galaxy A6 and my Nexus 5x.

On the Galaxy there is no problem on the receiving side. The file is download in the "Download" folder and I get the path for the file from the intent, just like it's explained in the [android dev](https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/receive-files) page.

On my Nexus 5x the file get downloaded in the "beam" folder, but from the intent I get "beam/beam/file.txt" and I have to manually remove one of the "beam" in the path.

Why the hell is this happening?

And even if I managed to remove the "beam" part from it, I still miss the complete path to the file.

While on the galaxy the path from the intent is

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/...
```

On my nexus 5x is just:

```
beam/beam/...
```

Just.... what?

Is there anyway I can fix this or do I manually have to check if the beam folder is in the external or internal memory and then add the correct prefix?

Currently this is the code I use to retrieve the path when handling the "view intent" that should contain the file I received:

```
mIntent.data?.also { beamUri ->
        val pathSegments = beamUri.pathSegments
        var path : String? = beamUri.path

        // Edge Case for Nexus 5X
        if(pathSegments.size == 3){
            if((pathSegments[0] == pathSegments[1]) && pathSegments[0] == "beam"){
                path = "${pathSegments.first()}${File.separator}${pathSegments.last()}"
            }
        }
        ...
}
```

**EDIT 1:** Logging beamUri as suggested in the comments below, on the nexus 5x, the file is received as a content and on the Galaxy as a file.

I'll now implement the method to deal with content as well, but why the difference between the two?

Comment: what is `beamUri` like? try to log it with `Log.d`

Comment: beamURI is (depending on the device as written before) `/storage/emulated/0/Download/...` or `beam\beam\...`

Comment: no, Uri starts with scheme like file:// or content:// etc

Comment: Oh, apparently is received as a file on the Galaxy and as a content on my nexus 5x.

Comment: so you have the answer for your question

Comment: Thank you. But why are those two thing received in two different ways? The file being sent is the same for both of the devices

Comment: this is the same way: you have Uri, now read ContentProvider API docs on how to read data from your Uri

Comment: Yes, it's been solved. I'd like to know why on some devices I can access it as a file while in other devices I need to use a content  provider.

Comment: you have to always use `ContentResolver` when dealing with `Uri`s - i just realized that i told you to read `"ContentProvider API docs"` - of course its `ContentResolver` - sorry for that ;-(